# Specifying private key on PuTTY command-line

Tags: ssh, command-line, putty, private-key

I know there are simple commands to login to remote machine through VBA i.e. by specifying `User@hostname` and `-pw` option to provide the password in `Wshell.Run` function where `Wshell` is `CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`.

However I need to use private key file (specified under *Connection/SSH/Auth* option in PuTTY) while logging in through Excel-VBA macro. Is there a way to do it?

I need it because I am using admin account on the second form of my VBA code (First form is using user's own account) and hence cannot provide the password textbox on the second form. Hence the only secure solution is to use SSH login through public and private key.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use the [`-i` switch](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-identity) to specify the private key.

```
putty.exe username@example.com -i mykey.ppk
```

See [PuTTY command line documentation](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline).

Comment: Working (as it should OK with Kitty too).